# php file exists problem - 1000's of files

Tags: php, validation, file

I have a folder that contains 1000+ sub folders. In each subfolder there are 1-800 images, plus a thumbs folder with the same number of smaller versions. In total there are around 18000 photos and 18000 thumbs

I have created a script to run occasionally to check if everything is present (all paths, folders and photo names are stored in database).

Using either `file_exist()` or `is_file()`, plus `clearstatcache()`, I run a loop to my db records to check if everything is ok.

To check if the script actually works, I have included a check field in my table structure:

`photo_present, SET(Y,N)`

Each time I run the script each photo validated will have the `photo_present` flag set to `Y`.

After only a few records, 300-800, the script gives an internal server error 500.

I checked my table and I know that the script has run for a while since I see the `photo_present` field is set to `Y`.

My question is how to optimize it so either `file_exist()` or `is_file()` will continue to work until all the files have been checked?

Comment: Do you have access to the server's error logs? Look up what the exact reason is for the 500 error.

Comment: yes - i scan my error logs and see nothing severe there, other than the fact that 20-25 jpg files are missing.
I can only assume that the internal server 500 error is referring to script timeout after observing the script's behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you running the script? If it's by hitting the web page, it could be that your server caps the runtime of a script at 30 seconds or so and is killing PHP after that time, resulting in an Internal Server Error. The same could be true if it's being run via cron, but that's less likely.

Comment: Actually i use it by hitting the web page. Any suggestions otherwise?
i cant setup a cron

Comment: @andrew: Make your script faster, contact your hosting provider about increasing the timeout or switch to a host that supports cronjobs.

Comment: You should try set_time_limit(600);  That will let the script run for 10 minutes (if you host lets you modify that part of the runtime env)

Comment: Matt, i tried setting it to 600, 300 and even 0 for unlimited, but i still get that error after a while and before the script stops executing. Now i am searching to something to simulate crontab as i dont have direct access

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure this isn't a script timeout? Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

I myself consider glob being a good alternative when browsing folders and files, you might be able to figure out something.

```
<?php
//get all image files 
$files = glob("{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.gif,*.GIF,*.png,*.PNG,*.cr2,*.CR2,*.DNG,*.dng}", GLOB_BRACE);

//print each file name
foreach($files as $file)
{
    //Do your db validation here.
    //echo "<a href=\"$file\" style=\"display:block;\">$file</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: i tried set_time_limit(600) and even 300 and 0 ans still not good. Also, i only jpg files so the rest of your code is of no use to my scenario (me thinks)